# Top links only show all when customer is logged in

Tags: layout

I've eliminated all of my top links with the exception of:

> Login
>
> My Cart

I've done this by commenting out the appropriate sections in my themes *customer.xml* file.

Now what I would like to do is have the following display when the customer logs in:

> My Account
>
> Compare
>
> Wish list

I have tried to place the layout information as follows for *My Account* however I haven't be able to get it to work:

```
  <customer_logged_in>
    <reference name="top.links">
<action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log Out</label><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/><title>Log Out</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
<action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_in>
```

**How can I display the customer specific links only when they are logged in?**

Comment: Seams like you are in the right track. everything you place in the layout handle `customer_logged_in` will be loaded only when the customer is logged in. You should place there your links.

Comment: Looks like you are correct Marius! I have no idea why it wasn't working but none the less, I couldn't find anything specific about this when I was searching so I'll leave it be and others can benefit. SR

Comment: Just so this question would have an answer, please post the final form of your xml layout file as an answer and accept it.

Comment: I've answered it but unfortunately I have to wait 2 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final xml modifications are the following:

```
    <customer_logged_in>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log Out</label><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/><title>Log Out</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
        <label>Compare</label>
        <url>catalog/product_compare/index/</url>
        <title>Compare</title>
        <prepare>false</prepare>
        <position>20</position>
        <target>_blank</target>
</action>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_in>
```

This will show only Log Out, My Account and Compare in the top links menu for customers that are logged in. When logged out only Login.

Note: I have the wishlist disabled in the admin panel.